# How many zeros are in the Cayley table for multiplication mod n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is [stated without proof](https://oeis.org/A018804) that the number of zeros in the Cayley table for multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is given by the gcd-sum function $\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)$, for all positive integers $n$.

I can show this is true for small values of $n$ and for $n$ prime, but proof for a general $n$ eludes me.

Comment: Let's have this, just for the record: https://oeis.org/A018804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of zeroes in the Cayley table is  $z_n:=|\{(x,y)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2: xy=0\}|$. To obtain your formula let's count the cardinality of this set in a different way. Fix $x\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, so $x$ can be identified with an element in $\{1,\dots,n\}$, we count the number of elements $y\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $xy\equiv 0\pmod{ n}$.

We are done if we can show that this number is $\gcd(x,n)$. Let $k=\gcd(x,n)$ and assume $km=n$. Since $k=xr+ns$ for some $r,s\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have that if $xi\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ then $km=n\mid ki$, so $m\mid i$. This means that the additive order of $x$ is $m$, so the cardinality of $\langle x\rangle=\{xy\pmod{n}: y\in\{1,\dots, n\}\}$ is $m$. This implies that the cardinality of $\{y:xy\equiv 0\pmod{n}\}$ is $n/m=k=\gcd(x,n)$. Therefore
$$z_n=\sum_{x=1}^n\gcd(x,n).$$

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but shouldn't it be xyr = ky (mod n)?  Then I see that there are k solutions to xyr = 0 (mod n).  How does this imply that there are k solutions to xy = 0 (mod n)?

Comment: @MM393 woops! that was a mistake. see the corrected version

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It seems to me, however, that you have shown that the additive order of x is a multiple of m.  I think you still need to argue (somehow) that xm = 0 (mod n).  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: I see it now!  Since x = kt, for some t, xm = kmt = nt.